A math Olympiad problem about angles in a triangle
Question:
Consider an acute-angled triangle $\Delta ABC$ with $\angle C > \angle B > \angle A$. $(*)$
Let $x$ be the maximum value of $\text{min}\{\angle B - \angle A, \angle C - \angle B, 90^\circ - \angle C\}$ among all triangles satisfying condition $(*)$.
Find the value of $x$.
Rough idea of the solution:
$x$ is attained by a triangle with $\angle B - \angle A = \angle C - \angle B = 90^\circ - \angle C$. $(**)$
Together with the condition $\angle A + \angle B + \angle C = 180^\circ$, the values of $\angle A$, $\angle B$ and $\angle C$ can be solved.
My question:
Why is $(**)$ true?

Since the previous answer was deleted, I will answer my own question.
Rewrite $\angle C - \angle B = 180^\circ - \angle A - 2\angle B$ and $90^\circ - \angle C = \angle A + \angle B - 90^\circ$.
The idea is that say $\angle B - \angle A < 180^\circ - \angle A - 2\angle B = \angle A + \angle B - 90^\circ$, then by slightly decreasing $\angle A$ and increasing $\angle B$, the minimum will increase.
